# this.state is null inside render function

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

I am writing some code in react-native and when i am using this.state inside render function  it is showing it to be a null object

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  TextInput,
  Text,
  View,
  AppRegistry,
  Image,
  StyleSheet
} from "react-native";
import Greet from "./compo/greet";

export default class App extends Component {
  Constructor(props) {
    Super();
    this.state = {
      test: "nothing to display"
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.view}>
        //here is where error is coming[enter image description here][1]
        <Text> {this.state.test} </Text>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          keybordType="default"
          placeholder="enter the secret "
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

This shows up a error
"Type error null is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.test')"
it simply mean that this.state is null
what to do

Comment: Is it because your `constructor` is capitalized instead of being lowercase? (same for `super()`)

Comment: writing constructor in lowercase shows an error

Comment: @HARSHBAJPAI It shows an error because `Super()` with a capitalized `S` is not defined inside the `constructor`. Javascript identifers are case-sensitive, which means that `Super` and `super` do not point to the same function. `super` inside a constructor is always bound to the constructor of the class you are deriving from, in this case `Component`. `Super` is in your case `undefined` and therefore not callable at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful with the letter casing of constructor and super.

```
   constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state={
        test:"nothing to display"
      };
    }
```

This should work, ES6 class constructors MUST call super if they are subclasses.

Comment: it will take me 8 mins to accept your answer but i will accept it in 8-10 mins

Comment: @HARSHBAJPAI no need to write thank you. You thank someone by marking the answer as being correct (checking the checkmark next to the answer) and up vote.

Answer (score -1):

You have a casing issue. Also, it seems that `styles` is `undefined`:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import {
    TextInput,
    Text,
    View,
    AppRegistry,
    Image,
    StyleSheet
} from "react-native";
// import Greet from "./compo/greet";

export default class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super();
        this.state = {
            test: "nothing to display"
        };
        this.styles = {
            view: "display: block;",
            input: "display: block"
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={this.styles.view}>
                <Text> {this.state.test} </Text>
                <TextInput
                    style={this.styles.input}
                    keybordType="default"
                    placeholder="enter the secret "
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/5x12zyyr0l